# Visualisation of plane cutting cone in perpendicular lines

Tags: analytic-geometry, 3d

I came across a problem which requires to prove that plane $ax + by + cz=0$ cuts cone $xy+yz+xz = 0$ in perpendicular lines if $1/a + 1/b + 1/c = 0$

Solution to the problem says that since given cone is generated by three mutually perpendicular planes, hence plane $ax + by + cz=0$ will cut it in perpendicular lines if **normal to plane through vertex (0,0,0) lies on cone itself**.

I am unable to visualise graphically how such a plane can cut cone in perpendicular lines. Why is it necessary for normal to plane through $(0,0,0)$ to lie on cone?

I am assuming that lines being referred in question are the boundaries of the cone which plane would touch when cutting across cone. Any graph/picture would be thankful.

Comment: This cone is the surface of rotation of any of the coordinate axes about the line $x=y=z$. So in particular, each of the coordinate planes intersects this cone in a pair of perpendicular lines: two of the coordinate axes.

Comment: Is it possible to visualise this somewhere?

Comment: You could plot the cone and play around with various planes through the origin in Wolfram|Alpha or a tool like GeoGebra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Plane cutting cone in perpendicular lines]

You can see here for interactive graph

```
https://www.geogebra.org/3d/ag7rjf5c
```